# How can I call a function where the argument is produced by another function?

Tags: c++, function, arduino, fastled

I'm controlling a strip of LEDs using an Arduino and the FastLED library and I've set up a few functions that allow me to change the colour of LEDs and the like.

I have a function where the values for red, green and blue are passed in, and it sets the entire strip to that colour:

```cpp
void changeColour(int valR, int valG, int valB) {
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++) {
        led[i] = CRGB(valR, valG, valB);
      }
      FastLED.setBrightness(255);
      FastLED.show(); 
}
```

I then set up a 2 dimensional array of preset colours and their corresponding RGB values:

```cpp
int colours [20][3] = {
  {255, 105, 180}, //HotPink
  {255, 20, 147}, //DeepPink
  {139, 0, 0}, //DarkRed
  {255, 0, 0}, //Red
  {255, 69, 0}, //OrangeRed
  {255, 255, 0}, //Yellow
  {128, 0, 0}, //Maroon
  {50, 205, 50}, //LimeGreen
  {0, 255, 0}, //Lime
  {34, 139, 32}, //ForestGreen
  {0, 128, 0}, //Green
  {0, 100, 0}, //DarkGreen
  {102, 205, 170}, //MediumAquaMarine
  {0, 255, 255}, //Aqua
  {0, 139, 139}, //DarkCyan
  {0, 191, 255}, //DeepSkyBlue
  {0, 0, 255}, //Blue
  {128, 0, 128} //Purple
};
```

What I'd like to do is to call the `changeColour();` function and pass in the RGB values of a random colour from the array, so I wrote that function:

```cpp
int randomColour(); {
  int x = rand() % 18;
  int valR = colours[x][0];
  int valG = colours[x][1];
  int valB = colours[x][2];
  return (valR, valG, valB);
}
```

How would I get it so I can call the `changeColour()` function but instead of `changeColour(valR, valG, valB)` it calls the `randomColour()` function which in turn returns the `valR, valG` and `valB` values, thus passing them into the `changeColour()` function?

Comment: first off: `randomColour` doesn't return what you think it returns

Answer (score 0):

You can't return multiple values (that easily) from a function in C++. Your `randomColour` function is in fact only returning one value, `valB`, since it's the last value in the expression `(valR, valG, valB)`.

An easy way to do what you ask would be to have `randomColour` return a pointer into the `colours` array, and then overload or change `changeColour` to accept `int` arrays. So then instead of using `valR`, `valG`, `valB` inside of that function, use `colorReference[0]`, `colorReference[1]`, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I needed to clarify that a bit more. You can't return multiple values from a function without special structures and syntax, right? Such as tuple objects and the like?

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that `randomColour` returns an `int`, just one not 3.

`(valR, valG, valB)` this uses the comma operator, which evaluates all the operands in order (in this case this is a nop) and the whole expression evaluates to the last operand, i.e. `valbB` which is what you are returning.

The simplest and the most appropriate is to create a structure for the RGB colors:

```
struct Rgb
{
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
};

void changeColour(Rgb color) {
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++) {
        led[i] = CRGB(color.r, color.g, color.b);
      }
      FastLED.setBrightness(255);
      FastLED.show(); 
}

Rgb colours [20] = { /* ... */ };

Rgb randomColour() {
    int x = rand() % 18;
    return colours[x];
}
```

and the function you want is as simple as this:

```
void changeToRandomColor()
{
    changeColour(randomColour());
}
```

---

I must also point out Arduino lib has its own random function: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/random-numbers/random/ and I suggest you consider it instead.

Comment: Thank you, I think I can see what's going on here. I set it up as you have, but when I run the program it gives the error "variable or field 'changeColour' declared void"? It's also worth noting that the idea of the `changeColour` function was that when it is called the input is either the actual RGB values or have a function that chooses them randomly - not sure if thats actually possible

Comment: _variable or field 'changeColour' declared void_ - please, double-check for typos. Such error could be reported if you made a typo in `Rgb` argument of that function.

Answer (score 0):

C++11 and more has tuples which you can use, but you also have other options to do this..

1 : You can return a struct containing r g b values and return it from randomColor().

2: Change randomColor() to accept output parameters.. references.

```
void randomColor(int &r, int &g, int &b) {
    int x = rand() % 18;
    r = colours[x][0];
    g = colours[x][1];
    b = colours[x][2];
}

void changeColor() {
   int r, g, b;
   randomColor(r, g, b);
   std::cout << r << " " << g << "  " << b << std::endl;
}
```

3: The max value of the colour is 255.. So you can simply use a 4 byte integer to pad pack the three values and unpack them using bit manipulation.
something like this.

```
unsigned int randomColor() {
    unsigned int r = 11;
    unsigned int g = 22;
    unsigned int b = 33;
    return r << 16 | g << 8 | b;
}

void change_color() {
    unsigned int rgb = randomColor();
    unsigned int b = rgb & 0xFF;
    unsigned int g = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
    unsigned int r = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
}
```

Returning a struct is the simplest and cleanest solution.